# HibernateValidator 5 seems to not cascade validation on JPA entities

Tags: hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

I have a problem with Hibernate and Hibernate Validator 5. I have some entity, let's say `Group` and another entity `Person`. They are related as follows: Group has two references to Person - contact person and manager. They are both one-to-one relationships with full cascade and orphan removal options.

What I want is to validate the contact person and the manager while the group is being saved. The more, I want a different validation group to be used to validate contact person and manager. In order to do this, I placed `@ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = ContactPersonValidation.class)` together with `@Valid` before the contact person field and I did it analogously for manager field (using different validation group).

Now, Hibernate validation does not work - I mean that the group is not converted to the one provided in `@ConvertGroup`. I followed the source code of Hibernate validator and it seems to  validate Group object and two Person objects separately. Therefore, Person validation is not cascaded from Group object and the validation group is not converted.

Have you ever experienced a similar problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: It would help if you show the actual annotated entities and how you save/persist the entities. Are you using the native Hibernate Session or JPA? How do you do validation? Do you rely on life cycle based validation?

Comment: I am using native Hibernate session and I rely on the life cycle based validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During lifecycle validation triggered by JPA, Bean Validation uses a `TraversableResolver` which doesn't follow up assocations also if they are marked with `@Valid` (see 3.6.1.2 "Requirements for Automatic Validation upon Lifecycle Events" of the JPA 2.0 spec).

So your `Person` objects won't be validated by following up references from `Group` but they will be validated when they themselves are persisted. Thus the group conversions declared on `Group` don't apply.

You can implement the behavior you want by defining a [GroupSequenceProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e2886) for `Person` (note that this is a Hibernate Validator specific feature). For that purpose, you would have to pass the "role" of a person (e.g. in form of an enum with values `Contact` and `Manager`) to the `Person` instances. The default group sequence provider could then access the role and apply one or the other validation group if a given `Person` instance is persisted.

Comment: I know that it uses `TraversableResolver` and it doesn't follow up associations. I have already done this in the way you described (with use of GroupSequenceProvider), but I hoped there is some trick to do this in better (or maybe "cleaner") way :)